# InAppSettingsKit with multiple plists

Tags: ios, inappsettingskit

I am looking for a pretty advanced settings framework for iOS.

First, I would like to use custom editors for some settings (user can select colors).
If I read correctly, this is feasible with IASK.

I have not found a answer though for my second issue.

Our app is fairly broad with 3 or 4 different "areas" and we would like to have settings on an "area" basis.
This is definitely not possible with standard settings but is it possible with IASK?

This could be either thru different plist or different Childpanes in the same plist but then it would require being able to start the editor from a given Childpane.

Many thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom editors are definitely possible using `IASKCustomViewSpecifier` (see the Readme).

Regarding the areas, I'm not sure if 1) the areas are structurally the same and you just want to store the user settings separately, or if 2) they are completely different.

1. If your areas have the same set of settings and you just want to
   store them separately, you can use separate subclasses of
   `IASKAbstractSettingsStore`. If you want to store all settings in
   `NSUserDefaults` you can subclass `IASKSettingsStoreUserDefaults`
   instead.

   In the implementation you can either use different `NSUserDefaults`
   instances (instead of `standardUserDefaults`). Then your subclass
   would just need to override `-init` and store a different
   `NSUserDefaults` instance in the `defaults` property.

   Alternatively, you can use a prefix to the settings key. For this
   you'd have to override all setters and getters to insert your
   prefix.
2. If you're merely interested in having separate settings screens with
   different settings, you can instantiate one
   `IASKAppSettingsViewController` instance for each area and set the
   `file` property to the name of the settings plist for each area. The
   same mechanism is used internally for child panes, so you could also
   add a parent page with `PSChildPaneSpecifier`s for each area. This
   would even work with the system settings.

Comment: Thx @ortwin, I have started the integration in my app and it is looking good so far.