# How can I reuse a plist file with InAppSettingsKit?

Tags: inappsettingskit

When using [InAppSettingsKit](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit), I see a few ways that different plist files are used, 1) when using a childpane or 2) when using a list.

I want to be able to reuse a plist file but have the keys for the different settings be different. This would allow me to reuse the same file but have different settings stored.
ie. something like: `CommonSettings.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSMultiValueSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>A_COMMON_SETTING</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>${unique}_setting_value</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Note: I'm already taking the values/titles using the `valuesFor` and `titlesFor` delegate methods for the `PSMultiValueSpecifier`.

One way I though about doing this was using the list functionality without an *Add capability* but that didn't work since the AddSpecifier seems required even though the documentation states:

> Optionally, a list group also has an AddSpecifier

(My program crashed without it)

Note: I did take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43497309/inappsettingskit-with-multiple-plists) but I'm already comfortable using different `plist` files, I'm looking to reuse them.

Answer (score 0):

IASK doesn't support a dynamic variable resolution in plists. However, you should be able to achieve this with a custom build script that generates the different plist files at compile time from one master file with variable replacement. Use `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` to work with plist files.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; are there any ways to use the delegate or extend `IASKAppSettingsViewController` to support the scenario I mention? The challenge for me is not generating the plist files, it just seems redundant and possibly avoidable.

Comment: No, currently IASK doesn't support this and it's not on our roadmap. Feel free though to extend it according to your needs.